# Android: one handler for all runnables?

Tags: android, handler, runnable

Can I use one handler in my Activity for all runnables or should I have multiple instances of Handler, each for one runnable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use only one `handler` and to specify from where your are coming use different message.

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(messagevalue);  //use this to send message from different place
```

Now handle message

```
    private Handler handler=new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        //specify msg value
        if(msg.what==10){
            //do this
        }else if(msg.what==20){
            // do this
        }else{
            //so on....
        }
    }  
   };
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using postDelay(runnableName, 100); so I always explicitely say which runnable will exectue after specified miliseconds. So I guess it's OK to use only one handler. Thanks.

Comment: If we use handler.postDelayed(runnableName, 100); statement multiple times with different runnable is this ok ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that you should have one handler per thread (not per runnable), unless you do not need completely different behavior for different kinds of runnables.

Comment: If we use handler.postDelayed(runnableName, 100); statement multiple times with different runnable is this ok ?

Comment: @Julian I think it's something easy to test isn't it ?

Comment: @TamimAttafi yeah but I wasn't sure if it was correct to do that or not