# What is better for instructions at roughly the same time: multiple Handlers with single Runnable each, or single Handler with multiple Runnables?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I want several things to go off exactly at once while trying to maintain a light resource load. For example, play sound and updating GUI at the same time. Is it better to have multiple handlers with single runnables or a single handler with multiple runnables running in parallel?

I'm aware that the below implementation won't actually run at the same time and be offset due to instructions in runnable1 potentially being longer than runnable2 thus (runnable1 execution time + 3000) vs (runnable2 time + 6000), etc. But let's just say 3000 and 6000 are substitutes for calculated time to make it run every three seconds (take the difference in milliseconds of next interval [e.g. 00:00:03.000, 00:00:06.000] and the current time).

```
private Handler handler1 = new Handler();
private Handler handler2 = new Handler();

   protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
          Runnable runnableH1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              /* playSound A,B,C, etc every three seconds */
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                }
            }
        };

          Runnable runnableH2 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              /* change GUI A,B,C, etc every six seconds */
                    handler2.postDelayed(this, 6000);
                }
            }
        };

      handler1.postDelayed(runnableH1, 0);
      handler2.postDelayed(runnableH2, 0);
   }
```

vs

```
private Handler handler1 = new Handler();

   protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
          Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              /* playSound A,B,C, etc every three seconds */
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                }
            }
        };

          Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              /* change GUI A,B,C, etc every six seconds */
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, 6000);
                }
            }
        };

      handler1.postDelayed(runnable1, 0);
      handler1.postDelayed(runnable2, 0);
   }
```

I'm aware that there are similar questions:
[Android: one handler for all runnables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274265/android-one-handler-for-all-runnables)
But the answers say you can only use one handler when from my reading of the Android documentation it sounds like you can implement multiple handlers w/o issue (else the IDE would complain, which it doesn't) to have multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if in the end all you are doing with the handlers is changing views or any other task that will be added to the main UI, you can have a single handler attached to the main Looper and or several of them, in the end all of your handlers(or your single handler) will be piping messages into a single queue, "the main thread UI queue", so, there's no real advantage from a "parallelism/multithreading" stand point.

Personally I would avoid having several handlers because it would be error prone and chances to get leaks are higher...

On the other hand, if you are not pushing your messages to the main thread and in stead you are just doing some work in parallel, then several threads is the way to go, not necessarily several handlers since you actually don't really need them unless you need to publish something into the main thread.

Hope it helps!

Regards